# Client Class Error in Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, int

Now, I also just have a simple question on the client class below, an error I'm getting, how to fix that error, and properly print (this.toString())

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IndexClient
{
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    System.out.println(this.toString());
}
```

Basically, I am getting an error on the second to last line that says identifier expected right before the after the println and before the first parentheses. Why am I getting that error, how would I fix that error, and then how would I successfully print (this.toString())?

Update Number 1:

I am not sure that this is entirely necessary; however, if you need it, my toString() method is below:

```
public String toString()
{
    String sb = "";
    for (int d = 0; d < words.size(); d++)
    {
        sb += "The word: " + words.get(d) + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Update Number 2:

I really appreciate all the help and constructive criticism of the code that I can get. I hope I didn't turn this simple question into one too complex. Thank you very much :)

Update Number 3:

I am sorry for leaving so many notes. However, I was only just wondering if this is a common question that any of you guys see a lot because it seems like this comes up a lot in class, and the teacher assisstant can't answer the question. Thanks again :)

Comment: `teacher assisstant can't answer the question`, that´s really sad, the thing you did wrong is programm within your class but not withing a method. throw these the print line inside a method and you´re fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use :

```
System.out.println(toString());
```

Out side a method, you can use it inside a method or you can create your main method :

```
public void myMethod(){
   System.out.println(toString());
}
```

Or

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I forgot to put public static void main String[] args. I am so stupid

Comment: `this.toString()` is not working in a static method.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot have code outside a method in a java class.
2. You must create an object of your class to access `this`.

A correct minimal implementation would look like that (taken from the [Online Java IDE](https://www.compilejava.net/)):

```
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class

public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OtherClass myObject = new OtherClass("Hello World!");
    System.out.print(myObject);
  }
}

// you can add other public classes to this editor in any order
public class OtherClass
{
  private String message;
  private boolean answer = false;
  public OtherClass(String input)
  {
    message = "Why, " + input + " Isn't this something?";
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return message;
  }
}
```